# What is the partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

Let $0<\alpha<1, a_n= \frac{n!}{\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)..(\alpha+n-1)}$.

Is it possible to write the partial sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$  in a compact form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but I think you can rewrite the terms as $$a_n = \dfrac{1}{{\alpha + n - 1}\choose{n}}$$

Comment: thank u...but i already knew that..the reciprocal makes the sum difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $b_k=\frac{(k+1)!}{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+k-1)}$, and compute $b_k-b_{k-1}$.

Comment: your $b_k=\frac{(k)!}{\alpha (\alpha+1)..(\alpha+k-1)}$ or $\frac{(k+1)!}{\alpha (\alpha+1)..(\alpha+k-1)}$

Comment: $b_k=\frac{(k+1)!}{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+k-1)}$. Put $c_k=\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+k-1)$ Then $c_k(b_k-b_{k-1})=(k+1)!-k!(\alpha-2+(k+1))=(2-\alpha)k!$ and so $b_k-b_{k-1}=(2-\alpha)a_k$

Comment: You are welcome.